# Exchanging expectation and limits on a finite probability space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose I have an infinite sequence of random variables $X_n \rightarrow X $ a.s.

Suppose that the sample space $\Omega$ is finite.

Does it follow that *E*[$\textrm{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n] = \textrm{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[X_n]$ ?

It seems to me that it should follow, since given that $\Omega$ is finite, there should be a dominating r.v. and thus the dominated convergence theorem should apply. Is this correct?

(Apologies if this is a dumb question, I am not a mathematician by training.)

Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my comment. Using the extended dominated convergence theorem, I think this is true.

Comment: Why do you think "the conditions for the dominated convergence theorem to hold should be satisfied automatically"?

Answer (score -1):

**case your sum is diverging :**

a simple counter exmple :
let $\Omega$ = {-1;1} and define $(\epsilon_i)_i$ an infinite sequence of rademacher variables i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_i=-1)=1/2$ then :
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i]=0$
But we know that $S_\infty=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon_i$ is divergent so it can't have a finite expectation

Indeed if $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon_i]<+\infty$ then it would imply imediatly that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon_i < \infty$ a.s wich is known to be false (infinity will be visited i.o. it's a known proprety of the random walk, for a little more intuition on this see : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60417/will-a-random-walk-on-0-inf-tend-to-infinity)

**case your sum is converging :**

Here you have two options either your sum is made of positiv random variables and then Fubini-Tonelli applies without problem whatever the cardianality of $\Omega$
But if your sum is not made of positiv r.v. then it must satisfy absolute convergence to apply Fubini-Lebesgue theorem and so it still does not depend on the cardinality of $\Omega$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Many thanks!
In your example, the sequence of random variables doesn't converge a.s.

I really meant to ask: if we have a sequence of random variables that does converge a.s.,  and Ω is finite, then does it follow that there is a dominating random variable (and thus that we can exchange expectation and limit, by the dominated convergence theorem)?

Apologies if this is an elementary question. (I am a philosopher, not a mathematician).